# sendto() blocked when the buffer was full, how to solve it?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, block, sendto

I wanna make a chat room for 4 guys in UDP. Here's the code:

```
<code>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#define PORT 9999
#define SIZE 1024
int c;
int i=0;
int k=0;
char name[4][20];
char ip[4][16];
FILE * txt;
struct sockaddr_in seraddr,cliaddr[3],getcliaddr[3];

void gettxt()
{
    txt=fopen("ip.txt","r");
    for(k=0;k<4;k++)
    {
        c=fgetc(txt);
        while(c!=' ')
        {
            name[k][i]=(char)c;
            i++;
            c=fgetc(txt);
        }
        name[k][i]='\0';
        i=0;
        c=fgetc(txt);
        while(c<'1'||c>'3')
            c=fgetc(txt);
        while(c!='\n')
        {
            ip[k][i]=c;
            c=fgetc(txt);
            i++;
        }
        ip[k][i]='\0';
        i=0;
    }
    for(k=0;k<4;k++)
        printf("<%s>%s\n",name[k],ip[k]);
}

int compare(struct sockaddr_in whichcli)
{
    int w=1;
    for(w=1;w<4;w++)
    {
        if(whichcli.sin_addr.s_addr==cliaddr[w].sin_addr.s_addr)
            break;
    }
    return w;
}

int main()
{
    int com;//compare return value (just the "k")
    int qq;
    int ret;
    int ser;
    int maxsock;
    char bufrecv[SIZE];
    char bufsend[SIZE];
    socklen_t clilen=sizeof(cliaddr[1]);//the same wa ~~I guess

    gettxt();

    fd_set readfds;

    seraddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    seraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip[0]);
    seraddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);

    for(qq=1;qq<4;qq++)
    {
        cliaddr[qq].sin_family=AF_INET;
        cliaddr[qq].sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip[qq]);
        cliaddr[qq].sin_port=htons(PORT);
    }
    ser=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    bind(ser,(struct sockaddr*)&seraddr,sizeof(seraddr));

    if(STDIN_FILENO>ser)
        maxsock=STDIN_FILENO;
    else 
        maxsock=ser;

    while(1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);  
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO,&readfds);
        FD_SET(ser,&readfds);
        ret=select(maxsock+1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,0); 
        if(ret>0)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO,&readfds))
            {
                fgets(bufsend,SIZE,stdin);
                for(qq=1;qq<4;qq++)
                    sendto(ser,bufsend,SIZE,0,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr[qq],clilen);
            }
            if(FD_ISSET(ser,&readfds))
            {
                for(qq=1;qq<4;qq++)
                {
                    recvfrom(ser,bufrecv,SIZE,0,(struct sockaddr*)&getcliaddr[qq],&clilen);
                    com=compare(getcliaddr[qq]);//
                    printf("<%s>%s\n",name[com],bufrecv);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
</code>
```

The file "ip.txt" is just the name-IP file, shows as follows:

```
<txt>
I 192.168.1.2
Sun 192.168.1.4
Jerry 192.168.1.5
Peter 192.168.1.6
</txt>
```

The first contained the information of my own, the following 3 were other guy's.
But when I ran the program with only one guy, first of all, we can chat with each other with nonblocking. After several words, it didn't work well. I ran gcc and I guessed that when the "sendto" buffer was full, it blocked waiting the other "recvfrom" the buf. The program I wrote is for 4 guys, but I just ran it with only one guy, the other two can't recvfrom it(still the buffer in "recvfrom" I guess,am I right?). So the "sendto" buffer was full and blocked.
    That is what I think,am I right? 
    If it's true, and how to solve it? I mean how to clean the "sendto" buffer periodically? Or there is some other way? 
    Thanks very much ~~;-)

Comment: You make the socket non-blocking, and check for an error from `sendto` with `errno` set to `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your logic, when a client sends you message you loop through all the clients and call `recvfrom`, you should only call `recvfrom` once for each time `select` returns.

```
if(FD_ISSET(ser,&readfds))
{    
    struct sockaddr_in src_addr;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(src_addr);
    recvfrom(ser, bufrecv, SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr, &addrlen);
    com=compare(src_addr);//
    printf("<%s>%s\n",name[com],bufrecv);    
}
```

**Edit:**
It seems that you use `getcliaddr` in `recvfrom` as the `src_addr` which means that each time you receive a message from a client you *overwrite* the address of another client, this is not a problem for one client but for more than one you could overwrite the first one with the sender's address and you if you call `recvfrom` again it would block because you think it's waiting for the *first* client when it's actually waiting for the *second* one.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the meaning of the src_addr parameter to recvfrom(2):

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                 struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

`src_addr` is an OUTPUT from this function, not an input.  It should point at an empty `struct sockaddr` which it will fill in with the source address of the packet that was received.  This means that you can't pick a particular client to receive a packet from (and you don't really want to, as you don't know who is going to be typing next).  Instead, you just receive a packet, and then figure out who it was from.